# CSS linear-gradient vertical positionning

Tags: css

Here is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nnrgu/1/

And here i change to background-position:0px -70px and see what's happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/nnrgu/2/

linear-gradient, it's gone!

I'm doing it wrong or it's supposed to work this way?
How to move linear-gradient with background-image **together** or keep linear-gradient **unmovable**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
background-position: 0 -70px, 0 0;
```

does the trick. Since you declare multiple background-images comma-separated, you can declare for each image a single position, also comma-separated.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnrgu/3/

I even prefer the shorthand:

```
background: <color> image1 position1 repeat1 attachment1, image2 position2 repeat2 attachment2, ... ;
```

This way it is clear which position/repeat belongs to which image with less characters.

<sub>Sidenote:When you have `0` as value, just omit the unit.</sub>

Comment: Woah sure it does. Thanks, didn't knew that. +1 and accepted :)